# Basic rails crud in ajax with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I have a basic CRUD  in rails and ajax, but I need to integrate Devise gem,  when adding devise gem to my project and test the CRUD, I get this error:

[image: Controller error view]

[image: code inspector error in browser]

the controller code in rails 4.2:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :product_find, only: [:show, :update, :destroy, :edit]

  def index
    @products = Product.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def show

  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render layout: false }
      format.json { render json: @product }
      format.js
    end

  end

  def create
    @product = current_user.products.build(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product}
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    @product = Product.update(params[:id], product_params)
  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
  end

  private

    def product_find
      @product = Product.where(id: params[:id]).first
    end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :quantity, :price)
    end
end
```

The user can connect without problems, the error occurs when I create a new product with the registered user

what am I doing wrong?

I think the error may be in the CREATE and NEW method

thank!

Comment: are you sure that your user was signed in when you got the error?

Comment: the user can connect without problems, the error occurs when I create a new product with the registered user

Comment: is `current_user` non-null when you get the error?

Comment: I think the error may be in the CREATE and NEW methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set up the associations correctly for your models? The error `undefined method 'products' for <User>` suggests that you haven't.

```
# user.rb
has_many :products

# product.rb
belongs_to :user
```

Make sure you also have a `user_id` field on the Product model.

Comment: Exactly !, noob mistake, i add current_user.products.build in new method and current_user.products.build (product_params) in create method

Thank very much for your help